# Replace values in a pandas column using another pandas df which has the corresponding replacements

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df named `inventory`, which has a column containing `Part Numbers` (AlphaNumeric). Some of those part numbers have been superseded and I have another df named `replace_with` containing two columns, `'old part numbers'` and `'new part numbers'`. 
For example:

Inventory has values like:

```
* 123AAA
* 123BBB
* 123CCC
......
```

and replace-with has values like

```
**oldPartnumbers**   .....        **newPartnumbers**  

* 123AAA        ............            123ABC
* 123CCC          ...........          123DEF
```

SO, i need to replace corresponding values in inventory with the new numbers. After replacement inventory will look like as follows:

```
* 123ABC
* 123BBB
* 123DEF
```

Is there a simple way to do that in python? Thanks!

Comment: Is `df['part_numbers'] = df['new_part_numbers']` sufficient ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say you have 2 df as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[5,4],[6,7]], columns = ['PN','name'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[2,22],[3,33],[4,44],[5,55]], columns = ['oldname','newname'])
```

df1:

```
    PN  oldname
0   1   3
1   5   4
2   6   7
```

df2:

```
    oldname  newname
0   2        22
1   3        33
2   4        44
3   5        55
```

run left join between them:

```
temp = df1.merge(df2,'left',left_on='name',right_on='oldname')
```

temp:

```
    PN      name     oldname    newname
0   1        3         3.0      33.0
1   5        4         4.0      44.0
2   6        7         NaN      NaN
```

then calculate the new `name` column and replace it:

```
df1['name'] = temp.apply(lambda row: row['newname'] if pd.notnull(row['newname']) else row['name'], axis=1)
```

df1:

```
    PN  name
0   1   33.0
1   5   44.0
2   6   7.0
```

or, as **one liner**:

```
df1['name'] = df1.merge(df2,'left',left_on='name',right_on='oldname').apply(lambda row: row['newname'] if pd.notnull(row['newname']) else row['name'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

Consider the dataframes `inventory` and `replace_with`

```
inventory = pd.DataFrame(dict(Partnumbers=['123AAA', '123BBB', '123CCC']))

replace_with = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        oldPartnumbers=['123AAA', '123BBB', '123CCC'],
        newPartnumbers=['123ABC', '123DEF', '123GHI']
    ))
```

**Option 1**
*`map`*

```
d = replace_with.set_index('oldPartnumbers').newPartnumbers
inventory['Partnumbers'] = inventory['Partnumbers'].map(d)

inventory

  Partnumbers
0      123ABC
1      123DEF
2      123GHI
```

---

**Option 2**
*`replace`*

```
d = replace_with.set_index('oldPartnumbers').newPartnumbers
inventory['Partnumbers'].replace(d, inplace=True)

inventory

  Partnumbers
0      123ABC
1      123DEF
2      123GHI
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is relatively fast - it uses pandas data alignment and the numpy "copyto" function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'partNumbers': ['123AAA', '123BBB', '123CCC', '123DDD']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'oldPartnumbers': ['123AAA', '123BBB', '123CCC'],
                    'newPartnumbers': ['123ABC', '123DEF', '123GHI']})

# assign index in each dataframe to original part number columns
# (faster than set_index method, but use set_index if original index must be preserved)
df1.index = df1.partNumbers
df2.index = df2.oldPartnumbers
# use pandas index data alignment
df1['updatedPartNumbers'] = df2.newPartnumbers
# use numpy to copy in old part num when a new part num is not found
np.copyto(df1.updatedPartNumbers.values,
          df1.partNumbers.values,
          where=pd.isnull(df1.updatedPartNumbers))
# reset index
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

df1:

```
  partNumbers updatedPartNumbers
0      123AAA             123ABC
1      123BBB             123DEF
2      123CCC             123GHI
3      123DDD             123DDD
```